# Retrieve IE proxy username and password

Tags: http, wininet

I want to retrieve proxy username and password from IE7
Here is my code

```
CString UserName; 
LPINTERNET_PROXY_INFO ProxyInfo; 

DWORD dwSize; 
InternetQueryOption(NULL,INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY,NULL,&dwSize); 

if (dwSize > 0)
{
    BYTE * lpszData = new BYTE [dwSize]; 
    InternetQueryOption (NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, lpszData, & dwSize); 
    ProxyInfo= (LPINTERNET_PROXY_INFO) lpszData; 
    InternetQueryOption (NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_USERNAME, NULL, &dwSize); 
     if (dwSize> 0) 
     {
         lpszData = new BYTE [dwSize]; 
         InternetQueryOption (NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_USERNAME, lpszData, &dwSize); 
         UserName = lpszData; 
         delete [] lpszData; 
     }
}
```

InternetQueryOption with INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY works fine. But when I use it with INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_USERNAME or INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_PASSWORD, it fails with dwSize equal to 0. GetLastError function returns error code 12018.
Any idea why these functions fail?

Answer (score 1):

Those functions will only work if the user has already authenticated to the proxy (by typing credentials in the popup prompt) *inside the current process*. Until they do so, WinINET *doesn't have* the proxy credentials, and the result will be empty.

The result will also be empty if the proxy is only relying upon the user's current Windows login credentials via NTLM or Kerberos.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Already I have authenticated to the proxy. Also username and password has been saved by remember password option in popup prompt. Also what do you mean by "inside the current process"? Can you please explain how it will work? Or is there any other alternative?